# Time for an [encryption] tag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, tags

So, we have a [ceasar-cipher](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ceasar-cipher) tag, but not the more general [encryption](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encryption) tag. A quick [search](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=Encryption) shows over 200 questions that should potentially have such a tag.

What do you think? Is it a good tag? I can create tags, but wanted to get the thoughts of the community first.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=Encryption+is%3Aquestion returns 125 results; your quick search includes answers - still, 125 is more questions than several other tags have.

Comment: Status-declined, but no mod comment. Explanation please?

Comment: @Pimgd even though I have an answer here arguing for the creation of the tag, I have been convinced that it's not useful because [tag:cryptography] already covers it. As we grow, it may be worth revisiting, but for now I'm accepting rolfl's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Uhm.... No

We already have [cryptography](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptography) ... is there a difference?

Maybe there's a need to retag some questions, and I can see a need to make encryption a synonym to cryptography.

Comment: Agreed.  A synonym would be okay, at least if there are a large number of encryption questions.  Otherwise, just [cryptography] will suffice.

Comment: Encryption is a subset of cryptography. As is hashing. They are not the same. One is part of the other. Just throwing that out there.

Answer (score 3):

I think [encryption](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encryption) would be a useful tag. There are currently [125 candidate questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=Encryption+is%3Aquestion) for such a tag. (Thank you @Mat'sMug for the improved search.)

It was pointed out that [we already have a cryptography tag](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2006/41243), but encryption is just a subset of crytography; along with hashing. [SO has a tag for it](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/encryption/info) as well. I'm of the opinion that more specific tags lead to better categorization. One may want to follow questions about encryption, but not hashing and vice versa.

Quote from a [relevant discussion on Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/218076/256822):

> The difference between cryptography and encryption on the other hand
>   is entirely practical. Most questions that have to do only with
>   encryption are correctly tagged with encryption and most questions
>   that have to do with anything else are tagged cryptography. That's
>   useful to me and both have enough followers to merit a split.

Comment: What next, a tag for decryption?

Comment: Decryption should probably be a synonym of encryption to keep things clean. So, honestly, yeah.

Comment: @200_success Relevant Meta question that was discuss for SO http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217994/should-decryption-tag-be-synonymous-with-encryption

Comment: Can you be an expert in encryption without being an expert in cryptography in general? Yes, I think you can. Can you be an expert in decryption without being an expert in encryption? Doesn't compute.

Comment: I couldn't agree more. So maybe rather than a synonym for encrytpion & decryption, perhaps an [encryption-decryption] tag @otus?

Comment: @ckuhn203, might be too verbose. Nothing wrong with having no decryption. There is such a thing as excess symmetry.